# Is "cutting in" necessary when painting vinyl siding?

Tags: painting, exterior, vinyl-siding

I watched a [video](https://youtu.be/a_tbAG6f96k) that sugggested using a smaller roller first, to "cut in" under the fold of the siding:

[image: "cutting in"]

Then they used a larger roller for the whole width of the segment of siding.  Do I have to use the smaller roller first as in the video?  If so, please explain the purpose and what exactly I need to do to the edge of the roller for going under that little fold, or what exactly to buy as a roller cover.

My siding is vinyl but the shape looks similar to the video.  The long horizontal things are a little bit less wide than in the video.

Comment: And here I thought the whole point of vinyl siding was not having to paint it...

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I forgot to explain, I am painting the house because it's a yucky, depressing color.

Comment: Everything needs paint eventually. I painted my 1950s home, which was over-sided with actual aluminum (rare these days), probably in the 1970s. In the early aughts I painted it due to severe fading (and a very outdated color). It lasted very well until I sold in 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obviously have to coat the bottom face of each lap. How you do that is at your discretion, but full-size rollers don't make it easy. You'd need a big, sloppy paint load to get good coverage, and this leads to dripping and splatter.

I've traditionally used a brush for the undersides. Do that first, then roll over the brush marks on the vertical face. Don't work in direct sunshine if you can help it, since latex dries quickly and you won't get the brush marks rolled out well.

There's a plethora of edger devices out there. Some may be worth a try. There are no rules about this sort of thing, so use what works for you.

Comment: Thank you.  I saw this approach in some other videos.  Sounds good.  I have to use a brush for the edges (at the corners of the house) anyway.  Thank you also for the tip about the sun.